# How to build codeigniter login page and session with one controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

Hi. I am having a problem with my sessions, I am new to CodeIgniter, so please be patient with me. Here's my index function:

```
function index()
{
    $username;
    $pWord; //assume these two variables has valid and correct value
    if($this->coreModel->authenticate($username, $pWord)){
        $user = $this->coreModel->authenticate($username, $pWord);
        foreach($user->result() as $key) {
                $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                                'logged_in' => TRUE,
                                'cl_UserId' => $key->cl_UserId,
                                'cl_username' => $key->cl_username,
                                'cl_roles' => $key->cl_roles));
                if($this->session->userdata('cl_roles') == 1){
                    header("Location: ".base_url()."controller/homepage");  
                } else {
                    $this->load->view('loginPage',$this->data);
                }
         }

    } else {                            
        //$this->data['msg'] = "Wrong Username/Password";
        $this->load->view('loginPage',$this->data);
    }
}
function kickIfNotInSession(){
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == FALSE)
    { 
       redirect('controller'); 
    }
}
```

If I enter a valid username and password, it works fine, and the page goes to the homepage. In my homepage, I `echo` the `id` and `username`. Also in my homepage, I have a tabs menu. In all of the pages, I `echo` the `id` and `username`. I have also added a kickIfNotInSession() function in all of the functions, for example:

```
function test() {
    $userid = $this->session->userdata("logged_in");
    $this->kickIfNotInSession();
    $this->load->view("test");  
}
```

Also, I have **autoload.php**:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

After logging in, I clicked all the tabs and for some reason it works fine. It echoes the `id` and `username`, but after a minute or two when I click my tab, it kicks me out of sessions and directs me to the login page. I wonder how that happened. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check sess_expiration parameter in application/config/config.php file. May be it set incorrect.

> 'sess_expiration' = the number of SECONDS you want the session to last. by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).  Set to zero for no expiration.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your session expriation set to a very low value that throwing you out after few minutes.

Goto `application/config/config.php`, scroll down and look for `$config['sees_expiration']`.
That's what sets the expiration time (in seconds). Change it to whatever works for you and try again.

You can also take a look at CodeIgniter manual [**here**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) (at the bottom of the page).

> sess_expiration - The number of seconds you would like the
>   session to last. The default value is 2 hours (7200 seconds). If you
>   would like a non-expiring session set the value to zero: 0

Answer (score 0):

You should increase session expiration time. To change expirationtime

- Open CI config file located path_to_project/application/config/config.php
- Find $config['sees_expiration']
- Now incrase expiration like $config['sess_expiration'] = 14400;

Note: Session expiration time will be consider in second.